# Locus of intersection of normals of hyperbola

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, locus

$\text{In general four normals can be drawn to the }$ $\text{rectangular hyperbola $xy = c^2$ from }$
$\text{any point P(h,k)}$

$\text{If these normals intersect the curve at }$ $A(ct_{1}, c/t_{1}), B(ct_{2}, c/t_{2}), C(ct_{3},c/t_{3}) $ $\text{and}$ $ D(ct_{4}, c/t_{4})  $respectively then A, B, C and D are known as feet of co-normal points.

The shortest distance of locus of P from the circle $x^2+y^2-24x+128=0 $ is?

My try:-

Analytically $t_{1},t_{2} ,t_{3},t_{4}$ are roots of the equation $ct^4-ht^3+ kt-c = 0.$

So taking it as f(x) we solve that f'(x)=0 must have 3 real and distinct roots and we again take a derivative f''(x) = 0 we get the roots as 0 and h/2c then $f'(0)f'(h/2c)<0$
From there I cant proceed further I am getting the locus as $y(y-x^3)=0$

But the answer is 4(√5 -1)
Pls help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the shortest distance between the circle $x^2+y^2-24x+128=0$ and the curve given by the locus of P.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666635/find-the-shortest-distance-between-the-circle-x2y2-24x128-0-and-the-curve)